# Vim grep causes characters to temporarily disappear

Tags: macos, vim

I am working through [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way" by Steve Losh](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com). In chapter 32 we build a grep command that puts results in the quickfix window. It looks like this:

```
:nnoremap <leader>g :silent :exe "grep! -R " . shellescape(expand("<cWORD>")) . " ."<cr>:copen<cr>
```

It basically works, but when I run it, it will cause characters to become (temporarily) invisible. If I close and re-open the file, the characters come back. Also, if I search for the invisible characters, they appear.

For example, if I run the command with my cursor on ``thedude'' on a block of text like this:

```
thedude@abides.org
print foo(bar)
print foo(bar)
```

The two ``print foo(bar)'' lines become invisible. Can anybody guess why this might be happening? I'm using the system default Vim v7.3 on OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with your Terminal settings, or the terminal emulation you are using. Can you try a different Terminal? Also, see if hitting Ctrl-L helps, as this redraws the screen.

Comment: It happens in both the Apple Terminal and an XQuartz X11 terminal. Ctrl-l does restore the invisible text.

Comment: I see the same thing.  Simplifying it a bit, I get odd behavior with `:grep! -R 'thedude' .`.  It shells out, as expected, but then it seems to hang.  Without the `-R` flag, I promptly get a `Press ENTER or type command to continue` prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes occurs when using an external command with the `:silent` command. You can read about it at `:help :silent` in the second to last paragraph. There it tells you that you can work around the problem by redrawing the screen after you execute the command or using `CTRL-L` to clear it manually.

```
:nnoremap (yadda yadda):copen<cr>:redr!<cr>
```