# Hide the output of shell commands in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I hide the output of any command in the form `:!command` in Vim. I don't want to get any messages from Vim after running this command (like `Press ENTER or type command to continue`) also. I want shell commands to run in background completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I want shell commands to run in background completely." --- This is not about Vim. It is about how to run commands in background.

To not print any output, you can run command like this: `yourCmd >/dev/null 2>&1`, if it doesn't work, use `nohup` (https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm).

To not print `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, you can execute commands in Vim like this:

```
:silent !<command>
```

`silent` blank-issue:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/silent-makes-my-vim-go-blank

[Vim grep causes characters to temporarily disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939040/vim-grep-causes-characters-to-temporarily-disappear)

Comment: After running `silent !<command>` line numbers and tildas disappear.

Comment: @Vuk  hmm, my ubuntu worked well but my Mac got the same problem like yours. For now I don't know why. I think it's because some vim plugins because the vim in my ubuntu has no plugin.

Comment: @Vuk  read these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939040/vim-grep-causes-characters-to-temporarily-disappear    https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/silent-makes-my-vim-go-blank

Comment: @Vuk type `:redraw!` to refresh the screen when finish your command

Comment: Thanks, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/vim-shell-commands-silence), you can also do:

```
:call system('command')
```